# Many-to-Many Delete/Remove failing w/ "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

Summary: Multiple many-to-many relationship add's using .attachto work fine, but the identical code, with the exception of being a .remove, rather than a .add, causes the dreaded:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

So here is the code.  Based upon form fields, one hidden (with the previous trainer value), one not, I cycle through a list of trainers to see which one's have been selected or deselected, then add or delete a many-to-many relationship between the Client and the Trainer:

```
Protected Sub dsClient_Updated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs) Handles dsClient.Updated
    Dim Client As Client = e.Entity
    Dim Trainers As IEnumerable(Of aspnet_Users), CurrentTrainer As String, PrevTrainer As String

    ' Select list of Trainers
    Trainers = From S In FitnessDB.aspnet_Users

    For Each Trainer As aspnet_Users In Trainers
        CurrentTrainer = Request.Form(Trainer.UserName)
        PrevTrainer = Request.Form("Prev_" & Trainer.UserName)
        ' Check if Trainer has been deleted
        If CurrentTrainer = "" And PrevTrainer <> "" Then
            ' Trainer previously existed, delete
            FitnessDB.Detach(Trainer)
            e.Context.AttachTo ("aspnet_Users", Trainer)
            Client.aspnet_Users.Remove (Trainer)
        ElseIf CurrentTrainer <> "" And PrevTrainer = "" Then
            ' Doesn't exist, add
            FitnessDB.Detach(Trainer)
            e.Context.AttachTo ("aspnet_Users", Trainer)
            Client.aspnet_Users.Add (Trainer)
        End If
    Next
    e.Context.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

I'm able to select multiple trainers to add just fine.  It cycles through:

```
FitnessDB.Detach(Trainer)
e.Context.AttachTo ("aspnet_Users", Trainer)
Client.aspnet_Users.Add (Trainer)
```

with no problem, with the new relationships added just fine.  If I delete just a single trainer, it works fine.  But if I attempt to delete more than one trainer using the code below

```
FitnessDB.Detach(Trainer)
e.Context.AttachTo ("aspnet_Users", Trainer) <-- Error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
Client.aspnet_Users.Remove (Trainer)
```

then I get the error on the second delete attempt.

So what's baffling me is: why can I successfully .attachto multiple "trainer" when .add'ing, but not when .remove'ing?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While I've posted a work around below, I would still love to know an answer to this if anyone has an insight they'd care to share.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I have come to the tentative conclusion that it's a bug within the Entity Framework for a variety of reasons I'm too tired to go into detail with here.

I have however figured out a workaround.  I've removed the code section above that was checking for trainers to delete, and replaced it with:

```
For Each Trainer As aspnet_Users In Client.aspnet_Users
    If Request.Form(Trainer.UserName) = "" Then DeleteTrainers.Add (Trainer)
Next
For Each Trainer As aspnet_Users In DeleteTrainers
    Client.aspnet_Users.Remove (Trainer)
Next
```

The entire sub as rewritten is now:

```
Protected Sub dsClient_Updated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs) Handles dsClient.Updated
    Dim Client As Client = e.Entity
    Dim DeleteTrainers As New List(Of aspnet_Users), CurrentTrainer As String, PrevTrainer As String

    ' Check for trainers that have been removed
    For Each Trainer As aspnet_Users In Client.aspnet_Users
        If Request.Form(Trainer.UserName) = "" Then DeleteTrainers.Add (Trainer)
    Next
    For Each Trainer As aspnet_Users In DeleteTrainers
        Client.aspnet_Users.Remove (Trainer)
    Next

    ' Check for trainers to add
    For Each Trainer As aspnet_Users In FitnessDB.aspnet_Users
        CurrentTrainer = Request.Form(Trainer.UserName)
        PrevTrainer = Request.Form("Prev_" & Trainer.UserName)
        If CurrentTrainer <> "" And PrevTrainer = "" Then
            ' Doesn't exist, add
            FitnessDB.Detach(Trainer)
            e.Context.AttachTo ("aspnet_Users", Trainer)
            Client.aspnet_Users.Add (Trainer)
        End If
    Next
    e.Context.SaveChanges()
End
```

By moving to using Client.aspnet_Users, I'm able to stay within the same context (e.context), thereby eliminating the problem of having to detach and reattach from the FitnessDB context to the e.context, which then crashes out when I remove the entity Trainer.

By looping first through the table of associated Trainers and adding them to a list, I'm then able to successfully remove them by looping through the list (I can't remove them directly within the table loop, as that errors out the loop with "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.".

Hope this helps someone someday.